# Is it possible to turn off a Cabal flag for older ghc?

Tags: haskell, cabal

In my project's .cabal file I have a flag to control where to use https.
However http-client doesn't build well with much older ghc versions...
Is there a way to change the default for the flag for older ghc?

I can't see one or any other workaround (other than ignoring the flag).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested, but I would guess something like this works.

```
flag foo
    if impl(ghc > 7.10)
         default: True
    else
         default: False
```

Even if not, you can at least make the error appear early by making each stanza unbuildable in bad configurations, e.g.

```
executable foo
    if (impl(ghc > 7.10) && !foo) || (impl(ghc <= 7.10) && foo)
        buildable: False
```

Comment: Good guess - I tried before posting and it doesn't work for me anyway.

Comment: I mean the first block doesn't work: but cabal-install-2.0 told me to file a bug. (I did something similar to your second block to workaround it.)